# Next.js app dir - Attempted import error for external dependency

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, server-side-rendering, tezos

I have a Next.js project with the `app/` dir that is using the `@taquito/beacon-wallet` package.

However, running my app in dev mode keeps giving me the following error:

```
./node_modules/.pnpm/@airgap+beacon-ui@4.1.0/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-ui/dist/esm/index.js
Attempted import error: 'effect' is not exported from 'solid-js/web' (imported as 'effect').

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/.pnpm/@airgap+beacon-ui@4.1.0/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-ui/dist/esm/index.js
./node_modules/.pnpm/@airgap+beacon-dapp@4.1.0_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@airgap/beacon-dapp/dist/esm/index.js
./node_modules/.pnpm/@taquito+beacon-wallet@19.0.0_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/@taquito/beacon-wallet/dist/taquito-beacon-wallet.es6.js
./src/lib/hooks/use-auth.ts
./src/components/auth/auth-modal.tsx
```

Now, I searched on their Github, and a lot on Stackoverflow, and have realized the beacon wallet SDK was not designed with SSR in mind

I have so far tried the following:

- Dynamically importing `BeaconWallet` into my `useAuth` hook (used inside `AuthModal`) with `use-auth` and `auth-modal` both set to `"use client";`
- Tried to override webpack config in `next.config.js` and set `config.resolve.fallback = { "@taquito/beacon-wallet": false }` when `isServer`
- Tried to dynamically import the entire `AuthModal` component in the higher-tier `layout.tsx` file
- Tried using `npm` instead of `pnpm` thinking it maybe a peer deps issue or symlink issue of some sort that sometimes happens with Next

None of it seems to be getting me anywhere. Any advice would be appreciated!